# Microsoft OMSAgent Listens on TCP port 16001

Tags: fluentd, oms

I have installed the Microsoft OMSAgent (on Linux). Now I see that it listens on TCP port 16001.

Neither the documentation nor grepping through the Sourcecode gave some hints why.

Anyone got an idea what services usually uses port 16001? fluentd? Is it safe to block it via firewall rules?